# Angular2 Documentation Generator

Tags: typescript, angular, documentation-generation, jsdoc

Is there a documentation generator (may be a node package) like in other programming languages (jsdoc / phpdoc / javadoc / ..) for typescript-based Angular2-Projects?

Comment: dgeni https://github.com/rangle/angular2-dgeni-starter

Comment: Ja, danke/thank you, I now, also this seed (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) has `npm run build.docs`. But I would need a independent library/package/etc..

Comment: I don't know where dgeny is maintained. I just posted the link to the starter pack because I assumed that it provides all the ingo how to use it.

Answer (score 15):

This seems to be a viable solution :[compodoc](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I found compodoc-project was the best solution in case you have an angular2-project. The documentation covers everything you might expect from good docs, compodocs can identify angular2 modules/classes/services/annotations etc. and structures the output accordingly... Also, i found the included docs-coverage report very useful. Didn't try it with a pure typescript project, put i guess this would look like the output for 'pure' classes without annotations.

Comment: I found this tool the best for my Angular + TypeScript project.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using TypeScript then "Typedoc.org" can be useful for you.
http://typedoc.org/

Comment: Ya, it got closed. I will find another

Comment: If you are going to use Typedoc, I recommend you to create your own conventions since the defaults are pretty basic. We took some inspiration [from here](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html).